# Make back to top icon visible if JS is not enabled

Tags: javascript, html

Ken Lee helped me with a script that will hide a back to top button and make it only visible if the user had to scroll. My problem is that the default state of many "back to top" functions including this one is "hidden". I don't know how many people disable JS in the settings...back in 2000 I had some friends that disabled it as it was risky etc.

Now I need a solution that will make the back to top icon visible if JS is not enabled...and hide it if the user did not have to scroll AND JS is on or make it visible if the user has JS enabled and had to scroll.

The code in the DIV reads "visibility:hidden"...but if I set it to visible, it will remain visible...unless I click the button, which will make it disappear. Please help me with a solution that will change the invisible state of the icon to visible if JS is disabled.

Code in DIV:

```html
<div id="bottomx" style="visibility: hidden">
  <img
    src="img/toparrow.png"
    style="cursor: pointer"
    class="icons"
    title="Seitenanfang"
    onclick="javascript:xtop();"
  />
</div>
```

Script:

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-eKhayi8LEQwp4NKxN+CfCh+3qOVUtJn3QNZ0TciWLP4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>

<script>
  function xtop() {
    $("#content").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow", function () {
      // Animation complete.
      document.getElementById("bottomx").style.visibility = "hidden";
    });
  }
</script>

<script>
  content.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    if (this.scrollY == 0) {
      document.getElementById("bottomx").style.visibility = "hidden";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("bottomx").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: The vast majority of websites these days need JS. I don't think you need to go out of your way to accomodate people who disable it.

Comment: But if you want to, you should do it the other way around. Make everything visible by default in CSS. Then use JS to show them selectively. If they have JS disabled, everything will be visible and the site will work.

Comment: Used to be we'd use a tiny snippet of JS to add a class to the `<body>` element, eg `<script>document.body.classList.add('js-enabled')</script>`. Then you can easily use CSS to hide / show other elements